# Check server response in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, response

I want to check server response in javascript. For example I have a server A which will host the script. On excuting the script it will check if the server B is responding or not. If yest continue other wise redirect to server C. Is this possible with Javascript/Jquery? If not what could be a possible solution in PHP?

Comment: If you're trying to make a fault-tolerant web service, there are much better ways than handling it in javascript.  Ideally, your web code wouldn't even be aware of server failures.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for php you can use [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) function

Comment: Thanks, that is of help but is it possible with javascript?

Comment: Nope, that looks like a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request to a known interface in each server. If the success callback is called, then the server is up and running. Otherwise (error, timeout) there is a problem.

Server development may be needed in order to make sure that there is a url you can safely call. Be warned that it could take some time for your script to report the error.

Answer (score 0):

Did You know AJAX doesn't work cross domain? It doesn't. Safety reasons.

So first thing is You have to use jQuery's getJSON or getScript

create an array of servers somewhere and loop through them saving current one somewhere and doing a query. if it responds - continue using saved one. if not - continue searching.

remember that Your calls are asynchronous and You have to make it work with callbacks and query error functions.